# Urban Airship / Parse vs rolling out your own solution for push notifications

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

What are the pros/cons of using UA/Parse vs your own solution. I'm not trying to set off a comparison, what I'd like to know is what benefit would you have in using their services (which costs money) vs rolling out your own solution with the various APIs (which costs nothing but your time + maybe some extra CPU cycles?).

I just feel like there's not much to gain from going with a third party service unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Parse is closing their service :
announcement here http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used both Parse and rolled my own solution. The custom solution powers an Android app with over 150,000 installs. And I have no reason to ever roll my own again now that I've found Parse.

One of the biggest factors for me is convenience. Yes, a third party service will cost money compared to using your own solution. And in terms of rote flexibility, a 3rd party will always be less flexible than coding your own solution.

However, at least with Parse, the Android libraries are very robust and quickly allow you to modify and intercept the needed functions for push notifications - opening, running an Intent, and posting open stats back to a server. Parse also has a console to send manual push notifications and a very easy hook to send push notifications via web.

My custom solution uses a wrapper library for the actual sending of the push notification, but I had to manually code the other functions. That means I had to handle sending a re-registration request from the app to the server when the GCM changed. I had to handle bounced messages. I had to handle the webhooks. I didn't have a console to manually send. I had to write my own receivers for Android.

I'm a big fan of 3rd party software because it allows me to focus on what matters most to me as an engineer - **my product**. I don't want to have to worry about supporting the full stack from phone to database for an app. Any small parts that I can offload drastically help my own bug list and workload.

What I've found is the minor cost for a 3rd party to handle this is worth it in the reduced stress of having one less system to worry about with my team.

**EDIT**

One of the things I didn't touch on is cross-platform portability of a solution like Parse. I only have to integrate my backend code into one database and make one call to send a push to Android, iOS, Windows, Blackberry, or Amazon. Supporting all those platforms, designing the database and dealing with errors takes time. And that's time that I could otherwise be focusing on building revenue-generating features.

From a learning standpoint, roll your own. From a production standpoint, use the tools that exist to reduce your own workload. It will help your company reduce unnecessary expenses, and that means more money for in-office perks like free lunch.